# Extracting text from find_next_sibling(), BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the description of the Chinese character from this website: http://www.hsk.academy/en/hsk_1

Example html:

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="hanzi"><a href="/en/characters/%E7%88%B1">爱</a></span>
                <br/>ài</td>
            <td>to love; affection; to be fond of; to like</td>
        </tr>
```

I would like the last td tag's text be put into a list for each description of the character. However, currently I am given the whole tag including the tags themselves. I can't .text the find_next_sibling(): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

This is my code:

```
for item in soup.find_all("td"):   
        EnglishItem = item.find_next_sibling()
        if EnglishItem:           
            if not any(EnglishItem in s for s in EnglishDescriptionList):
                EnglishDescriptionList.insert(count, EnglishItem)
                count += 1
            print EnglishDescriptionList
```

Comment: can you be more clear like what is the desired output. I did not understand the statement " I can't .text the find_next_sibling(): AttributeError:...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
english_descriptions = []
table = soup.find('table', id='flat_list')
for e in table.select('.hanzi'):
    english_desc = e.parent.find_next_sibling().text
    if not any(english_desc in s for s in english_descriptions):
        english_descriptions.append(english_desc)
```

This selects (finds) all tags of class `hanzi` (within the table with `id="flat_list"`) which will be the `<span>` tags. Then the parent of each `<span>` is accessed - this is the first `<td>` in each row. Finally the next sibling is accessed and this is the target tag that contains the English description.

You can do away with the `count` and just append items to the list with

```
english_descriptions.append()
```

Also, I don't think that you need to check whether the current english description is a substring of an existing one (is that what you're trying to do?). If not you can simplify to this list comprehension:

```
table = soup.find('table', id='flat_list')
english_descriptions = [e.parent.find_next_sibling().text for e in table.select('.hanzi')]
```

Comment: This code gives me the error:     english_desc = e.parent.find_next_sibling().text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: The code works with the HTML snippet that you included in your question, but there are 2 tables in the actual HTML document. I have modified the answer to restrict the search to the second table.